# iPhone multi-threaded AddressBook manipulation

Tags: iphone, multithreading, addressbook

I have been using the AddressBook api of the iPhone for some time now.  But doing some refactoring to improve application performance I have decided to "reuse" the ABAddressBookRef returned by AddressBookCreate because I noticed there are large performance improvements doing that.  However, I am getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS errors now randomly, and I think the reason is in this "caveat" in the iPhone reference implementation: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/300-BasicObjects/BasicObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW1

Important: Instances of ABAddressBookRef cannot be used by multiple threads. Each thread must make its own instance by calling ABAddressBookCreate.

Now, I thought that simply meant it was not thread-safe so I had to synchronise access to the API, but maybe I am wrong, and there is some other reasons multiple threads mess up the data structure?

Can someone confirm if it is indeed a thread-safe issue (so @synchronize should work) or some other issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a thread safety issue... there is no way for you to solve it with locks.  The comment makes it pretty clear:

> **Important**: Instances of ABAddressBookRef cannot be used by
>   multiple threads. Each thread must
>   make its own instance by calling
>   ABAddressBookCreate.

What you can do is create a single instance of the ABAddressBook and create a producer/consumer architecture that would manage the access to the object.

The wrapper will have a main thread which does one thing only: reads operation requests from a blocking queue, then performs the operations on the address book.  All your threads will queue their operations to the single queue and the wrapper will execute those actions; if there is nothing in the queue then the wrapper will block until there is something in the queue.

This should solve the problem of not being allowed to use the `ABAddressBookRef` from multiple threads.

Comment: Hi Lirik,

yes, I have gotten to the same conclusion...  it seems like a very bad way to build an AB framework to be honest.. the developer is left to build a (relatively) complex multithreaded solution to solve a common problem that should be architected, but what can one do.. I am going to have to wheel in the big guns and do it the hard way.. thank you!

Comment: Actually, I had built a different solution before reading your answer, where i kept a dictionary of ABRefs with thread names thinking (naively) that the iPhone recycles threads from a threadpool... but helas, no dice... it builds a new thread every time you detach one...  so I had finally gotten to your same conclusion

Comment: @Lirik and @Marko, I have the same problem. I have already seen the multi-threading issue and have implemented the AB wrapper pretty from the beginning. But I still have a huge bug - sometimes the app crashes and sometimes it deletes all the contacts from the AB. I have tripple-checked that all the methods that use AB instance do it from the thread that is managed by this wrapper.

Comment: Is there a chance that the use of ABContactRef that was retrieved from an AB also should be done from the same thread? In general, I read the contacts, compare them to the ones inside my app's CoreData DB and. If there are changes then I update the Core Data objects, if there are additions then I add them to the local Core Data DB etc. Any help will be more than appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael, unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Apple programming... I only answered that question because I'm familiar with threading. It looks like a more "in-depth" issue and I'd suggest you ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @Michael, according the documentation you cannot (or should not) pass record references across threads, either. Instead, pass identifiers (e.g. ABRecordGetRecordID). If I were to guess, I'd say this is because they reference for the ABAddressBookRef internally.