# App Crashes inside dispatch_queue in iPhone

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, abaddressbook

In one of my apps I am using dispatch_queue and inside this I declared a `dispatch_asyc` queue for checking the address book. Now when compiler comes to the return statement, it causes app to crash. Below is my source code.

```
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("abc", NULL);

   dispatch_async(queue, ^{
       // Request authorization to Address Book
       ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
       if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
           ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
               // First time access has been granted...

               // All good.
               completionBlock?completionBlock(YES):nil;

               dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                   if (addressBookRef) {
                       CFRelease(addressBookRef);
                   };
               });

               return;
           });
```

Comment: What crash message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation on Address Book](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html), you cannot use  ABAddressBookRef across threads

> **Important**: Instances of ABAddressBookRef cannot be used by
>   multiple threads. Each thread must make its own instance by calling
>   ABAddressBookCreate.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2382388/1804403) for some more ideas on how to do this: