# EXC BAD ACCESS in ABRecordCopyValue

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, abaddressbook

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem either while getting birthday or email for random people variable. I tried using the following code which fails when I run it using dispatch_async.

```
ABAddressBook addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
int maxThreads = 8;
int chunkSize = (int)(nPeople/maxThreads);

for (int loopNum = 0; loopNum < maxThreads; loopNum++)
{
    int initCondition = chunkSize*loopNum;
    int termCondition = (loopNum==(maxThreads-1)) ? (int)nPeople : chunkSize*(loopNum+1);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        for (int i=initCondition; i<termCondition; i++)
        {
            @try {
                ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

                NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)) ? (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)) : @"";
                NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)) ? (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)) :@"";

                NSString *birthDate = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty));

                ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
                NSArray *emailAddresses = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue);

                ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

                NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers)];
                for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++)
                {
                    NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
                    phoneNumber = [self removeSpecialChars:phoneNumber];
                    if ([phoneNumber length] >= 8)
                    {
                        NSString *mobileNumber = [self getPhoneNuber:phoneNumber];;
                        if ([mobileNumber length] > 7 && [mobileNumber length] < 11)
                            [numbers addObject:mobileNumber];
                    }
                }
                NSString *mobileNumbers = [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@","];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", exception);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the code without dispatch_async block, it runs without error. I want to do it with dispatch_async block to scan address book in parallel and detect any change from local database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation for ABAddressBookRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html) it states that these objects must be created and used on only one thread. Your code appears to create the `ABAddressBook` and the `AVRecordRefs` on the original thread, and then access them from the `dispatch_async` blocks. I would recommend finding another way to do this, where you create the `ABAddressBook` and the `AVRecordRefs` "just in time" on the background thread.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382388/iphone-multi-threaded-addressbook-manipulation) also has some more relevant information...

Comment: Thanks @ipmcc. But do you any solution to how to scan address book quickly with local contacts and find new contact info?

Comment: Not specifically. That sounds like a different issue. I would suggest you create a separate question.